# How to retain the existing html after the JQuery ajaxComplete html change

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery

I have got below **JQuery Code:**

```
 //Submitting the form
$("#loginDetails > form").submit(function()
{  
    //Hiding the Login button
    $("#loginButton").hide();

    //Showing the ajax loading image
    $("#ajaxloading").show();

    // 'this' refers to the current submitted form  
    var str = $(this).serialize();   
    // -- Start AJAX Call --

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",
        url: "Login.aspx",  // Send the login info to this page
        data: str,  
        success: function(result)
        {  

            $("#loginDetails").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
            {  

             // Show 'Submit' Button
            $('#loginButton').show();

            // Hide Gif Spinning Rotator
            $('#ajaxloading').hide();  

            var arr = result.split(",");
            var fname = arr[0];
            var lname = arr[1];
            var activeCardNo = arr[2];
            var multipleTier = arr[3];
            var activeStatus = arr[4];
            var access = arr[5];

             if(access!='') // LOGIN OK?
             { 
                var login_response = '<div id="logged_in">' +
                 '<div style="width: 350px; float: left; margin-left: 80px;">' + 
                 '<div style="width: 40px; float: left;">' +
                 '<img style="margin: 22px 0px 10px 0px;" align="absmiddle" src="system/images/ajax-loader.gif">' +
                 '</div>' +
                 '<div style="margin: 24px 0px 0px 10px; float: right; width: 300px;">'+ 
                 "You are successfully logged in! <br /> Please wait while you're redirected...</div></div>";  

                $('#loginButton').hide();
                $('#closeBtn').hide();
                $('#divMember').text(fname +' '+ lname);
                $('#spnSkywardsNo').text(activeCardNo);
                $('#spnTierStatus').text(multipleTier);
                $("#ui-dialog-title-skywardsLogin").text("Please wait...");
                $(this).html(login_response); // Refers to 'status'

                // After 3 seconds redirect the 
                setTimeout(closeDialog, 3000); 
             }  
             else // ERROR?
             {  
                 var login_response = result;
                 $('.validateTips').html(login_response);
             }


     });  

     }  

    });  

    // -- End AJAX Call --

    return false; 
});         



//Login Button Clicked
$('#loginButton').click(function()
{
    var bValid = true;
    bValid = bValid && checkLength( skywardNo, "Skyward No", 3, 16 );
    bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

    if ( bValid ) 
    {      
       $("#loginDetails > form").submit();
        allFields.val("");
        tips.text("");
    }
});
```

In above JQuery Code I am calling dailog modal popup on the click event of **#loginButton** button, and after all validations my form is submitted, in my ajaxComplete request above I am updating my existing html of the form with **"login_response"** html.

```
<div class="formContainer" id="loginDetails">
                <form action="#" id="frmLogin" class="homeWidget">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="formLabel" width="100">
                                <label for="skywardsNumber" title="Skywards Number">
                                    Skywards Number</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="formField" id="skywardsNumber" name="skywardsNumber" size="25" type="text" /></td>
                            <td class="formLink">
                                <a class="iconHelpBox" href="#">Forgot number</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="formLabel">
                                <label for="password">
                                    Password</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input class="formField" id="password" name="password" size="25" type="password" /></td>
                            <td class="formLink">
                                <a class="iconHelpBox" href="#">Forgot password</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
```

**Above HTML Code is replaced with below HTML code**

```
var login_response = '<div id="logged_in">' +
                     '<div style="width: 350px; float: left; margin-left: 80px;">' + 
                     '<div style="width: 40px; float: left;">' +
                     '<img style="margin: 22px 0px 10px 0px;" align="absmiddle" src="system/images/ajax-loader.gif">' +
                     '</div>' +
                     '<div style="margin: 24px 0px 0px 10px; float: right; width: 300px;">'+ 
                     "You are successfully logged in! <br /> Please wait while you're redirected...</div></div>";
```

Now everything works fine first time when I click login link, but after all above JQuery activity when I click second time login link same update html is coming.

Please suggest!

Comment: Not sure what issue is here? Any time the login link is clicked shouldn't the same login_reponse html fragment be returned if login is successful? Put another way, what should be returned the second time the login link is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, some quick tips for starters (correct me if I'm wrong in any of these cases!):

- Store references to the DOM elements you use often, such as `$("ajaxLoading")`, in variables. Otherwise, jQuery will have to search the entire document for this node every time you need it. Example: `var $ajaxLoading = $("#ajaxLoading");`
- Validate the form inside `submit()` function, since you cannot be sure that the form is submitted by clicking the submit button. For instance, the user may tab to the button and press enter (perhaps this triggered the `click` event? - not sure) or refresh the page after one form has been sent. If the form data supplied is not valid you return `false`, thus preventing the form from being submitted.

Regarding your problem, I don't think you need to use `.ajaxComplete()`. Try do something like:

```
$("#loadingDetails > form").submit(function(){

    // Show/hide, validate etc.
    // ...

    $.post("Login.aspx", serializedFormStr, function(result){

        // Build output from result string
        // ...
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks @afEkenholm, I just removed my ajaxComplete from code and some tweaks of Jquery and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand your description of the problem. However I do note one thing:

```
            $(this).html(login_response); // Refers to 'status'
```

In the "success" callback, I'm not sure that `this` will refer to anything useful. I don't know where that new HTML stuff is supposed to go, but you might try an explicit selector instead of `this` on that line.

Specifically, inside that "success" callback, `this` won't point to the form - it'll probably be the window object. You should probably save the `$(this)` reference in a variable and then use that variable in the success callback code.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy, Well I am trying to update the existing html, when my ajaxComplete is success i.e. it will remove intial form htmls with above htmls. and this refers to submitted form

Comment: any luck with the answer for issue @Pointy

Comment: uhh ... well have you tried changing `$(this).html(login_response)` to `$('#loginDetails > form').html(login_response)` ??